# What is Kirchoff's thermal radiation law?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation

Is Kirchhoff's law true even if body is not thermal equilibrium with surrounding. And according to Kirchhoff's law absorptivity is equal to the emissivity of body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Kirchhoff's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_law_of_thermal_radiation) states that:

> For a body of any arbitrary material emitting and absorbing thermal electromagnetic radiation at every wavelength in thermodynamic equilibrium, the ratio of its emissive power to its dimensionless coefficient of absorption is equal to a universal function only of radiative wavelength and temperature. That universal function describes the perfect black-body emissive power.

And yes it is valid; we also can postulate a relation between the coefficients of transmission, absorbtivity and reflection as $a_r + a_t + a_a = 1$.

Comment: Don't answer with a copied image only.

Comment: if its valid why not?

Comment: should i always right a answer again and again my time too is important

Comment: Why being so critical peeps! chill please!

Comment: @AdityaGarg People are trying to advise you about the expectations we have of site members. Please listen to them.

Comment: Ok ok  I will try